# Line plot with multiple lines pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to compare two players by showing a line graph of their points over the years.  I want a line for each player, on the x-axis the Year, and on the y-axis the average Pts for that year.  I can use a groupby to get the numbers but can't plot them separately on a graph.

```
        Name         Year   Pts
2264    Mike Evans   2017   10.7 
2266    T.Y. Hilton  2017   10.0 
2440    Mike Evans   2013   7.5 
10271   T.Y. Hilton  2013   12.4 
10499   T.Y. Hilton  2013   1.3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using **`pivot_table`** with **`aggfunc='mean'`**:

```
df.pivot_table('Pts', 'Year', 'Name', aggfunc='mean').plot(
          kind='line', marker='o', xticks=df.Year.unique()
)

# Pivot table produces:
# Name  MikeEvans  T.Y.Hilton
# Year
# 2013        7.5        6.85
# 2017       10.7       10.00
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`seaborn` is a very useful library for plotting `DataFrames`. For most plots, it allows you to specify a `hue` parameter that essentially groups your data for plotting.

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.pointplot(data = df.groupby(['Name', 'Year']).mean().reset_index(), 
              x='Year', y='Pts', hue='Name')
```

[image]